# What's importance of name: "Default" in Default Route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

I am learning basics of custom Route from [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_ARwj4_-fk). I understood that we need to create a Custom Route in addition to Default Route ...

I didnt understand whats the usage/importance of

> Name: "Default"

in the Default MapRoute. As a test, I changed `Name` attribute

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "aaa",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{Category}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

and run with URL

> ../MvcApplication2/Home/Index/cars

and the Application is still working fine. What is `Name: "Default"` used for?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the route is basically just a key that is used to **uniquely** identify that route and used to look up the route when you want to use a specific route.  The MVC framework will look at the url and determine where the user is trying to get to.

For example, using `@Html.RouteUrl("Default")` will build a url using the definition from the url and defaults you defined in the routes file.

Comment: ok . as far as i understand .. it is used when we look for a particular route from route collection .. and extract a particular route from it ... How change name : "aaa" will build a difffrent URL .. i mean where all it is happening actually ?

Comment: The MVC Routing Engine takes care of looking are the url pattern and matching the route.  It will start from the first rule in the collection and move all the way down to the last one trying to match it.  Just changing the name of the route won't affect if it is used by MVC.  That said, you should have a `Default` route at the bottom as a catch all so users don't end up at a 404 page.

Comment: I see...It also accepts null value ..just checked that